# problem in using stompjs using angular application

Tags: angular, websocket, stomp

This is my code for app component ts where I want to communicate to a websocket (for which I installed `sockjs-client` and `stompjs`). I don't know how to solve the error.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/socket'
  private title = 'WebSockets chat';
  private stompClient;

  constructor(){
    this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
  }

  initializeWebSocketConnection(){
    let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    let that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      that.stompClient.subscribe("/chat", (message) => {
        if(message.body) {
          $(".chat").append("<div class='message'>"+message.body+"</div>")
          console.log(message.body);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  sendMessage(message){
    this.stompClient.send("/app/send/message" , {}, message);
    $('#input').val('');
  }

}
```

This is the following error that I perform ng-serve:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\drnic\Desktop\Messaging app\Front-end\bantachat2\node_modules\stompjs\lib'
```

Comment: I have installed stompjs and sockjs-client

Answer (score 2):

Install dependency package 'net' using command

'npm i net -S'

Answer (score 0):

[Node stomp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stomp) is a serverside node.js package. This means that is expects the entire `node.js` stack to be installed and used, which isn't the case in an angular application.

That's why the problem is that the library can't find the `net` dependency. So basically you have installed the wrong thing.

[Check a very similar issue here](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/issues/119)

> https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/lib/stomp.js
>
> Is the browser file. The node one will only work in a NodeJS Environment. It calls require using some Node modules.